# Tkinter forgetting to finish the function

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am again asking a question on this progressbar project; although this should just be a clarification question.

My code causes for a progressbar to be created to track the creation of a file. The user selects the type of file they want to create and then hits "go" which causes for the file to begin changing and for the progressbar to appear. Progressbar works great. File writing/manipulation works great.

Problem: When the user selects several files to manipulate, despite the progressbars being created correctly, they do NOT update correctly. At first I thought that clicking on a button multiple times causes for tkinter to forget the root.after() function it was doing previously but after playing with a (much simpler) sample code I realized that this is not the case.
Question: How do I make sure tkinter doesn't stop implementing the first function even when the same function is restarted with different parameters?

Below are parts of my code to describe what I am doing.

```
progbarlock = False # start with the prograssbar marked as not occupied

class guibuild:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = root
        guibuild.progbarlock = False
        global theframe
        theframe = Frame(root)

        job_name = e.get()
        label = Label(theframe,text = job_name).pack(side=LEFT,padx =2)

        self.progbar = Meter(theframe) #makes the progressbar object
        self.progbar.set(0.0) #sets the initial value to 0
        self.progbar.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.counter = 0
        self.i = float(0) #i is the value set to the progressbar

    def stop_progbar(self):
        self.progbar.stop()

    def begin(self):
        self.interval()
        self.Status_bar()
        theframe.pack(anchor="s")

    def interval(self):
        if guibuild.progbarlock == False:

        guibuild.progbarlock = True


        def update(self):

            the_file = open('running_file.json')
            data = json.load(the_file)
            curr = data["current_line"]
            total = data["total_lines"]

            if self.i == 1.0:
                self.stop_progbar
                rint "100% - process is done"
                self.root.after_cancel(self.interval)
            elif curr == self.counter:
                 self.root.after(5000, self.interval)
            elif curr == self.counter+1:
                 self.i += 1.0/total
                 self.progbar.set(self.i) #apply the new value of i to the progressbar
                 self.counter += 1
                 self.stop_progbar
                 self.root.after(5000, self.interval)
            elif curr > self.counter+1:
                 self.i += 1.0/total*(curr-self.counter)
                 self.progbar.set(self.i) #apply the new value of i to the progressbar
                 self.counter = curr
                 self.stop_progbar
                 self.root.after(5000, self.interval)

            else:
                 print "something is wrong - running.json is not available"
                 self.root.after(5000, self.interval)


            guibuild.progbarlock = False



def start_process():
    makeRequest() #this is defined much earlier in the code and includes all the file creation and manipulation
    guibuild().begin()

button4 = Button(root,text="GO", command = start_process).pack()
```

NOTE:`makeRequest()` depends entirely on user input and the user input changes each time "go" is pressed.

Comment: Function with different parameters shouldn't stop previous function if they don't use shared/global variables. But you have to describe your problem more clearly.

Comment: Please fix the indentation so that the code is readable.

Comment: @ebarr I apologize for the formatting issues, I didn't realize that when I copied it the indentation changed.

Comment: @furas it was the global variables causing all the problems. Thank you so much for that suggestion!